# Unable to extract div html conent in scrapy python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am scrapping some data from this [URL](https://bbdealz.com/product/funny-sports-game-2m-3m-4m-5m-6m-diameter-outdoor-rainbow-umbrella-parachute-toy-jump-sack-ballute-play-game-mat-toy-kids-gift/)

I want to extract Description html div content

[image]

Here is my code

```
response.xpath("//*[@id='tab-description']/p").extract()
```

But it return extra ordinary data.

[image]

I want the output should be like

```
<p>    <strong>Brand Name: </strong>NoEnName_Null  <br>  <strong>Material: </strong>Cloth  <br>  <strong>Warning: </strong>2+  <br>  <strong>Function: </strong>Cooperation/Interpersonal Relations Developing  <br>  <strong>Dimensions: </strong>2/3/4/5/6 M  <br>  <strong>Design: </strong>Other  <br>  <strong>Age Range: </strong>&gt; 3 years old  <br>  <strong>Sports: </strong>Gymnastics  <br>  <strong>Type: </strong>Other  <br>  <strong>Gender: </strong>Unisex  <br>  <strong>Diameter: </strong>2/3/4/5/6 M  <br>  <strong>Material: </strong>210T Polyester fabric, 450mm water proof  <br>  <strong>Color: </strong>as the photo  <br>  <strong>handle number: </strong>8-28   </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://bbdealz.com/product/funny-sports-game-2m-3m-4m-5m-6m-diameter-outdoor-rainbow-umbrella-parachute-toy-jump-sack-ballute-play-game-mat-toy-kids-gift/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
info = soup.select_one('#tab-description').select_one('p')
print(info)
```